# O que são os valores de retorno do compareTo em Java?

Tags: java

Qual é a diferença entre os returnos 0, 1 e -1 do compareTo () em Java?

Exemplo:

```
Date date1 = '08/02/2019';
Date date2 = '08/03/2019';

date1.compareTo(date2);
```

Comment: A diferença é  0:`date1 == date2` , 1:`date1 > date2`, -1:`date1 < date2`

Comment: Muito obrigado.